# Restrict access to namespace in ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-ecr

I want to restrict an EC2 instance to EC2 container registry (ECR) repositories with the same [namespace](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/Repositories.html).

The IAM instance role should *only* can pull all repositories under `AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.REGION.amazonaws.com/test-namespace/...`. Nothing else.

I've tried the following IAM policy on an EC2 instance role:

```js
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1490955256000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy",
                "ecr:DescribeRepositories",
                "ecr:ListImages",
                "ecr:DescribeImages",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ecr:REGION:AWS_ACCOUNT_ID:repository/test-namespace/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But I was able to `docker pull` images from all repositories on that instance. E.g. `AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.REGION.amazonaws.com/test-repo:latest`

I don't see what I did wrong. It can't be the [resource-level permissions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/ecr-supported-iam-actions-resources.html). All of the above actions support them, except `ecr:GetAuthorizationToken`.

As we have many repositories, I don't want to do set resource permissions on each repository.

Answer (score 2):

`ecr:GetAuthorizationToken` does not support resource-level permissions.  You'll need to grant `"Resource": "*"` to the `ecr:GetAuthorizationToken` action.  The other actions can be restricted to the specific resources you wish to access.

In a policy, that would look like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1490955256000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1490955256001",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy",
                "ecr:DescribeRepositories",
                "ecr:ListImages",
                "ecr:DescribeImages",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ecr:REGION:AWS_ACCOUNT_ID:repository/test-namespace/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you please post where you saw this and explain why it's true?